# URL binding failure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have a asp.net 3.5 project. it worked perfect, but since i deleted some pages and my App_Data folder (because i didn't need them anymore), and i want to debug it from visual studio, it doesn't even launch anymore!
i am getting this IIS Express notification:

> **URL binding failure**
>
> cannot start the website because administrative privileges are required to bind to the hostname or port

i already tried to fix it by running visual studio as an administrator, but that didn't change anything.

**what is going on, and how to fix it????**

Answer (score 4):

After latest Windows 8.1 update I was unable to run my Webapp with the same Error, I was using custom port, port range that is allowed without Administrative privileges 44300 - 44399, so: 44300 port then.

Answer (score 1):

Open .**CSPROJ** file from project, Delete the whole lines for
  <DevelopmentServerPort> and <IISUrl> ...

http://gizmoblogr.com/821/workaround-url-binding-failure-error-iisexpress

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you run your VS as a administrator not your solution project? Its a difference between running VS and opening a solution.